# Confused by Boost bcp behaviour

Tags: c++, boost

I've downloaded Boost 1.57.0 and built bcp:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 tools/bcp/
```

I then tried to extract the `filesystem` module using `bcp`:

`./dist/bin/bcp filesystem ~/Desktop/test`

but the result is confusing: `test` now has 3 folders: `boost`, `docs` and `libs`. Both `boost` and `libs` include a folder called `filesystem` but the source files in those folders are different. Why do I have the `libs` folder? Do I import from `boost` or `libs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a C++ library, you need

- the headers at compilation (preprocessing) time.

  *They're under `boost`*
- the libraries at link time.

  *They're under `libs`*

Some boost libraries are header only. Some are optionally header-only. I think `b2` has an option to list which libraries need linking (and, consequently, building).

You'd call the "root" the BOOST_DIR (`BOOST_DIR=~/Desktop/test`). Therefore you'd add

```
CPPFLAGS+=-isystem $BOOST_DIR
LDFLAGS+=-L$BOOST_DIR/libs
```

and then depending on you needs:

```
LDFLAGS+=-lboost_system
```

etc. Of course, tailored to your favourite build system